# Операции в поле Галуа GF (2^8)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, криптография

Всем привет!

**1. Я пытаюсь найти обратный элемент в поле Галуа (2^8) по заданному модулю, но видимо у меня не хватает знаний чтобы понять.** В учебном задании сказано, что при реализации мы не можем хранить какие-то состояния, следовательно предполагается что нужно реализовать без таблиц степеней и логарифмов. Или можно было бы каждый раз генерировать при запуске программы заново таблицу, но наверное это странно если мы можем менять модуль с каждым запуском.
В википедии сказано что мы можем использовать расширенный алгоритм евклида.

Вот псевдкод:

```
 function inverse(a, p)
    t := 0;     newt := 1
    r := p;     newr := a

    while newr ≠ 0 do
        quotient := r div newr
        (r, newr) := (newr, r − quotient × newr)
        (t, newt) := (newt, t − quotient × newt)

    if degree(r) > 0 then 
        return "Either p is not irreducible or a is a multiple of p"

    return (1/r) × t
```

Меня в нём смущает строчка `quotient := r div newr`.
Я не понимаю как это работает, если у нас и `r` и `newr` - некие полиномы, а операция деления над полем не задана.
И то же самое с `1/r`. Ведь для деления нужно сначала найти обратный мультипликативный элемент.

Поясните эти вещи, пожалуйста и  можно ли как-то проще находить обратный элемент в заданном поле?

**2. Проверьте двоичный полином степени 8 на неприводимость
над (2^8);** В голову пришло только перемножать последовательно элементы и проверять, получается ли в процессе этот полином или нет. Но есть ли какой-то более адекватный вариант (не алгоритм Берлекэмпа,он для меня тоже не очень понятен), напишите, пожалуйста.
Буду благодарна за любые ответы, которые помогут лучше разобраться в теме.

Comment: `операция деления над полем не задана` - как делить многочлены, нас учили ещё в средней школе, `то же самое с 1/r` - в конце алгоритма degree(r)==0, поэтому r - это не многочлен, а число

Comment: Э-м-м, вы уверены, что неприводимые многочлены вам нужно искать именно на `GF(2^8)`, а не надо `GF(2)`?

Comment: Да, такой текст задания. По поводу деления многочленов, уже поняла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Концептуально самый простой способ вычислить обратный элемент - возвести элемент в 254 степень.

Обоснование. В поле GF(2^8) 256 элементов. В мультипликативной группе поля 255 элементов. Группа циклическая, порядок любого элемента является делителем порядка группы. То есть любой элемент в степени 255 должен давать единицу. Другими словами, для любого элемента `x` справедливо `1 == x * x^254`, следовательно `x^254` - обратное к `x`. Вычисление требует 15 умножений. Каждое умножение требует от 2 до 16 сдвигов.

Но с вычислительной точки зрения самый быстрый способ - расширенный алгоритм Евклида. Да, нужно деление с остатком, но для полиномов над GF(2^8) его реализовать несложно. Не более 8 сдвигов вправо на операцию.

Comment: `Группа циклическая, порядок любого элемента является делителем порядка группы` - а что, для не-циклических групп это неверно? )))

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! А при нахождении через алгоритм Евклида ax + by = gcd(a,b) мне нужно только найти x и это и будет обратный элемент к искомому?

Comment: @Новоевремя да, если b - неприводимый многочлен, который использовался для факторизации кольца многочленов R[GF(2)]. Обычно это полином Rijndael (0x11b), но бывают и другие. На каком неприводимом полиноме вы строите GF(2**8)?

Comment: Сейчас пытаюсь на 11, что должно быть эквивалентно x^3 + x + 1

Comment: @rebellieren этот полином порождает поле GF(2^3). Для поля GF(2^8) вам нужен полином восьмой степени. Например, 0x11b - полином, который используется для арифметики в AES.

Comment: Но у меня в задании сказано что нужно находить обратный элемент по заданному модулю в GF 2^8; Почему если я задам полином меньше восьмой степени, то я не найду обратный элемент? Вроде бы получаемый элемент получается меньше заданного полинома, соответственно я возвращаюсь обратно в поле